# What does MA ACA stand for?

Tags: meaning, british-english, abbreviations

This abbreviation [MA ACA](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22MA%20ACA%22) often appears after names on letters. What does it stand for?

I have seen it next to the signature on formal letters in this format: [First Name] [Surname] MA ACA.

The last time I saw it was on a letter from someone working for Deloitte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letters MA ACA represent two distinct qualifications.

The abbreviation MA is used quite generally to indicate a Master's degree in any arts subject (i.e. any non-science subject). It is an abbreviation of the longer term *Master of Arts*. People often just put these two letters after their name to indicate they have a master's degree. If they want the reader to know the subject of their master's degree they can put that information in words after the abbreviation. So it would look something like this:

- Bob Smith MA Linguistics

The abbreviation used to indicate a master's degree in a science subject is usually MSc, short for *Master of Science*.

In the UK, if you pass the necessary exams and gain the necessary qualifications you will become a member of the  Association of Chartered Accountants. At this point you are allowed to put the letters ACA after your name. This indicates that you are an Associate Chartered Accountant.

In English, it is common for people to list several qualifications after their name in formal documents. For example, a well qualified English language teacher might look something like this:

Bob Smith CELTA DELTA BA(hons) MA PHD

Answer (score 1):

> The last time I saw it was on a letter from someone working for Deloitte.

Deloitte provide financial auditing services, and are part of the [Big Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Four_accounting_firms). It stands to reason that the person is an accountant, which would mean that [Catija's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122822/what-does-ma-aca-stands-for#comment247472_122822) is probably correct: that the person holds a Master's Degree in Accounting and is a member of an association of chartered accountants (such as [ACCA](http://www.accaglobal.com/in/en.html), [ACAUS](http://www.acaus.org/), [ICAEW](http://www.icaew.com/), etc. based on the country), resulting in the "MA ACA".

**EDIT:** 
Given the OP is in London, the ACA would refer to the [*Association of Chartered Accountants* qualification](http://www.icaew.com/en/for-current-aca-students) given by the [ICAEW](http://www.icaew.com/).